# Why the difference between record count values

Tags: mysql

Actual my purpose is to find out the number of records present in my database so in order to find out that i have executed the query like **select sum(table_rows) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='database_name';** 
It gave me some value like 90658965

After that i need number of records present in the individual table so i have executed the following query **select table_rows,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='database_name';**
I have got result like **3781**(table_rows) and tickets(table_name)

So in order to cross verify i have executed the query like 
**select count(*) from tickets;**
I have got result like **3552**

why there is a difference between the count of tables for the above two query's
The storage engine for the **tickets** table is innodb

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES` Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/tables-table.html):

> For [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) table is partitioned.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME
```

this query is a resource incentive operation.

total return by  `information_schema.tables`  would be the right one